# How to know the number of user that register every day POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know how many users register every day.

But i don't have any idea how to make that.
You can find below the table.

[image: User table]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `group by`, assuming that "register" is defined by the `created_at` column:

```
select created_at::date, count(*) as num_created_users
from users
group by created_at::date;
```